# How to separate a parent and it's children when looping through a category?

Tags: categories

I have categories of cities and states set up as parents and children, for example:

```
California
  - Los Angeles
  - San Francisco

New York
  - New York City
```

When I use:

```
{% for place in entry.location %}
  {{ place }}
{% endfor %}
```

it returns to me the city state (for example: "Los Angeles California"). How can I separate out the parent and child? Ideally, I want to do something like this:

```
{{ place.child }}, {{ place.parent }}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a 2-level category, and you select one of the nested categories (`Los Angeles`), what you get in your entry is `Los Angeles` **and** its parent (`California`). There is no way to have `Los Angeles` without also `California`, though you can have `California` without `Los Angeles`. Anyway, that for loop `{% for place in entry.location %}` will loop over both of them.

One way to be more explicit about the cities and the states is to loop over just the cities using [level](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.categories#level) to fetch only the categories at a specific level in the category, and then for each city, fetch its ancestors with [ancestorOf](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.categories#ancestorOf). Your code would look like this:

```
{% for city in entry.location.level(2) %}
  {{city.title}},
  {% for state in craft.categories.ancestorOf(city) %}
    {{ state.title }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks Marion - this worked great! Appreciate it.